# Results in onCharacteristicChanged in array are not displayed properly

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I want to get every value of the array messageBytes in onCharacteristicChanged method but the logcat message is a bit messy. I have made my values in bold style. Any solution to get every single array value? Thanks.

> 05-05 17:57:15.763 14107-14119/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt E/BluetoothLeService: Puck:**[J[ 18, 30, 2.86,** 
>   05-05 17:57:15.800 14107-14119/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt I/BluetoothLeService: onCharacteristicChanged
>   05-05 17:57:15.800 14107-14119/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt E/BluetoothLeService: Puck:
>         **"normal"**
>        ]

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Service for managing connection and data communication with a GATT server hosted on a
 * given Bluetooth LE device.
 */
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback;

    {
        mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                String intentAction;
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                    // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                    setPuckCharacteristicNotification();
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead");
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged");

                byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
                String messageString = null;

                try {
                    messageString = new String(messageBytes, "UTF-8");

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to convert message bytes to string");
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Puck:" + messageString);
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite");


                BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(G.PUCK_SERVICE_UUID);
                if (service != null) {
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                            service.getCharacteristic(G.PUCK_TX_UUID);
                    if (characteristic != null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Writing to characteristic  " + characteristic.getUuid());

                        //String msg = "E.getTemperature()\n";

                        //byte[] data = msg.getBytes();

                        //characteristic.setValue(data);
                        if (gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "writeCharacteristic OK");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "writeCharacteristic FAIL");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

        // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
        // carried out as per profile specifications:
        // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
        if (G.PUCK_RX_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;
            /*if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
                Log.i(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            } else {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
                Log.i(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            }*/
            //final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            //Log.i(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
            //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
        } else {
            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for (byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
     *
     * @param address The device address of the destination device.
     * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    /**
     * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
     * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
     * callback.
     *
     * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
     */
    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    /**
     * Enables notification on a given characteristic.
     **/
    public void setPuckCharacteristicNotification() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        //Start getting data
        BluetoothGattService gattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(G.PUCK_SERVICE_UUID);
        if (gattService != null) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic = gattService.getCharacteristic(G.PUCK_RX_UUID);
            if (gattCharacteristic != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Setting Characteristic " + gattCharacteristic.getUuid());
                mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                BluetoothGattDescriptor clientDescriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(G.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
                clientDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(clientDescriptor);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
     * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
     *
     * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
     */
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }

    public int getElement(byte[] arrayOfBytes, int index) {
        return arrayOfBytes[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not post your question again . You received an answer so comment or modify your original question.

Comment: I want to take every value of the array separately. How can I achieve that?